# Organize methods for each primitives in Java

Tags: java, static, organization

I'm trying to **structure a bunch of static methods** I have coded such that they are easy to follow in groups. (I still have to read from and write in the console.)

In a "console" package, I have a Java class called "Read", which contains **nested classes** "Number", "NumberMinimum", "NumberMaximum"... that all contain methods to interpret each data types (Byte, Short, Int...) since generics don't apply.

- Console

  - Read

    - Number
    - NumberMinimum
    - NumerMaximum
    - ...

That way, I just import console.Read in my project class, and call my methods using Read.Number.getInt() for instance.

**Is there a better way to organize my methods than using nested classes?**

Comment: Yeah, just name them, e.g. `Console.getInt()`, `Console.getMinimumInt()`, `Console.getMaximumInt()`. Calling a class `Read` is not very descriptive of what is being read.

Comment: But then, I would have `Console.getByte()`, `Console.getShort()`, `Console.getInt()`, `Console.getLong()`... `Console.getByteMinimum()`, `Console.getShortMinimum()`...
I have a lot of methods that would go in that console class, like the minimum/maximum, within an array, and for all of those for each data types.

Comment: So?? What's wrong with that?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Is it better to have a single class of 48 methods - 40 of those methods being duplicates that handle the other primitive types - or to have 8 nested classes that contain each 6 methods that are practically the same? Is it better to group by purpose, or by data type, or to have everything in a single place?

Comment: Now that you've clarified what you're asking, I'm going to vote to close as "primarily opinion-based": *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* --- My opinion is that a single class with many methods is best. Sample class from the JDK doing exactly that: [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) (155 static methods)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should work with [`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class. It contains all method you want.

Take a look in this example:

```
public class Tests  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float number = 12;
        Read.setNumber(number);

        byte byteValue = Read.getNumber().byteValue();

        System.out.println(byteValue);
    }

    public static class Read{
        private static Number number;
        private static Number numberMinimum;
        private static Number numberMaximum;

        public static Number getNumber(){
            return number;
        }

        public static void setNumber(Number number){
            Read.number = number;
        }

        public static Number getNumberMinimum() {
            return numberMinimum;
        }

        public static void setNumberMinimum(Number numberMinimum) {
            Read.numberMinimum = numberMinimum;
        }

        public static Number getNumberMaximum() {
            return numberMaximum;
        }

        public static void setNumberMaximum(Number numberMaximum) {
            Read.numberMaximum = numberMaximum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods I'm trying to organize based on function (rather than data type) read values from the console (using Scanner(System.in)). The `NumberMinimum` nested class contains `readByte(byte minimum)`, meaning that the code returns a number read from the console that has to be grater than the minimum. My question was how should I refactor all those methods to be according to conventions I don't know yet.

Comment: Have you already heard about TDD? All code you want to produce, you should use TDD. It is the best approach to choose which kind of implementation you have to use to solve a problem. At first, create a test of what you want. After, produce the code to pass the test. Step-by-step, you will achieve what you want.

Comment: My code works fine both in a single class of in nested classes. I have written the tests, everything works. I'm at the "refactoring stage" of TDD - organizing the methods so that they make sense at first sight. Is it better to have a single class of 48 methods - 40 of those methods being duplicates that handle the other primitive types - or to have 8 nested classes that contain each 6 methods that are practically the same?